# Flask-Security @login_required decorator customize redirect

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

How would I override flask-security @login_required redirect URL?

Currently when an user tried to access a page with @login_required decorater; they're prompted to login page by default, however I want to be able to redirect user to /register page instead; since both login/register forms are combined together under one URL/Template. Is it possible to do so?

I've tried this so far and doesn't seem to be working.

```
SECURITY_UNAUTHORIZED_REDIRECT = '/register'
```

Comment: are you want to go to /register page before login? or its after login?

Comment: Either. I want to redirect user to login page if they try an access a view that has @login_required decorator.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** This works for `flask_login` package.

You can do this using [LoginManager.login_view](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_login.LoginManager.login_view)

In my app, I have used this like below:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

from app import views,models
```

Comment: That's not a solution using flask security. How would I implement this with flask security..?

Comment: Sorry, I have not used `flask-security` yet. The above solution is for `flask-login` package to redirect unauthorized access.